# How to manipulate the "onclick" event of a html button element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("RightButton").innerHTML="Back to Question";
document.getElementById("RightButton").onclick=GoBack();
```

Is the code I wrote to solve my problem. The first line successful changed the name of the button, but the second line simply doesn't work.

As you may have discovered, I'm totally a newbie. If you use excessive jargon, it will probably take me another question to figure out the jargon.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `()`. That way, you pass the function itself rather than calling it.

Answer (score 2):

`GoBack` is a function. Assign the function reference to the `onclick` property, but don't execute it immidiately with `()`. That way you assign the result of the call as the handler, not the function-to-be-executed when the element is clicked. Read more on event registration [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html).

```
var button = document.getElementById("RightButton");
button.innerHTML = "Back to Question";
button.onclick = GoBack;
```

As a note, conventionally only constructor functions use uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `GoBack()` function instead of assigning it to to the `onclick` event. Change your code to the below and you should be all set.

```
document.getElementById("RightButton").onclick=GoBack;
```