# Noob javascript, why is this firing onload?

Tags: javascript

So I dont understand why the console logs 1 right away onload or something when i have `one.onclick = alterIt(1)` shouldn't it wait till i click `one`. Anyway, obviously I am not ver good at javascript, thanks for your help.

```
window.onload = initialize;
function initialize() {
    if (1 == 1){
        calculation();           
    }
}
function calculation() {
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    one.onclick = alterIt(1);
}

function alterIt(x) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: but currently you have it written .onload?

Comment: okay, yeah, of course there is a duplicate, but in my situation how am i supposed to know what to search for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i add onclick to a Div via JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659564/how-do-i-add-onclick-to-a-div-via-js), [How to manipulate the "onclick" event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11702724/1048572) and [assign onclick event to function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3740761/1048572)

Comment: When I was learning JavaScript, the jQuery framework was very helpful.  You should check it out.

Comment: @watson: See this tutorial: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: First learn JavaScript, then use jQuery after you have understood the basics.

Answer (score 9):

When you wrote:

```
one.onclick = alterIt(1);
```

...then you invoked the `alterIt` function and set the return value as the `onclick` handler. Instead, you wanted:

```
one.onclick = function(){ alterIt(1) };

// ...or better yet
one.addEventListener('click',function(){ alterIt(1) },false);
```

Answer (score 4):

When the line `one.onclick = alterIt(1);` is executed, `alterIt(1)` is actually evaluated. What you want is to bind a *function* to `one.onclick`, which is only executed when the `onclick` event fires. You need something like

```
one.onclick = function() { alterIt(1) };
```

which doesn't bind the result of `alterIt(1)` to `one.onclick`, but rather the result of the function evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the function call like this so it doesn't fire until click:

```
window.onload = initialize;
function initialize() {
    if (1 == 1){
        calculation();           
    }
}
function calculation() {
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    one.onclick = function(){ alterIt(1);};
}

function alterIt(x) {
   console.log(x);
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RkH6Q/

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that you could code to work around this issue:

```
//Anonymous Closures
one.onclick = function(){ alterIt(1); };

//Bind Closures  
one.onclick = alertIt.bind(window, 1);
```

Note: Function.bind() is supported by all the browsers for a year. If you care about old browsers, anonymous closures is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

What is happening is that you are calling the `alterIt` function when you should just be passing it in. So remove the parenthesis like so:

```
one.onclick = alterIt;
```

Comment: No glory, since this does not properly preserve the parameter desired to be passed.